# MongoDB lookup with match not efficient in large amount of data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a two collection that **systems** and **systemsToUsers**. It is refer the **systems** _id as a foreign key **system_id** in a **systemToUsers** table. I need system data which all are _id not presents in the **sytemToUser** table.

I am using the below query but it is taking a long time (5 seconds) for 100 000 data. But need to optimize the query reduce the execution time

```
    db.Systems.aggregate([
    { $lookup: { 
from: 'systemsToUsers', 
localField: '_id', foreignField: 'system_id', 
as: 'systemswithusers' } },
    { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ { $size: '$systemswithusers' }, 0 ] } } }
  ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below `$match` and make sure every column in aggregate have **index**.

```
db.Systems.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "systemsToUsers",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "system_id",
      as: "systemswithusers"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      systemswithusers: []
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nL02M-kPYhc)